# How to add PWM control on raspi 4 motor robot on l298n motor driver

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am a fairly begginer in python and Raspberry Pi, I have this code shown down below, everything works fine but I have no idea how to control the PWM for the motors, in this code the motors are running at full speed. My question is, where and how to add the PWM declarations and changedutycycle calls?

Edit: For this particular code, i want to create a function that sets PWM to 50% of full power of all the motors, how can I create the function and how will I call it for all the moves that the robot should do (forward, back, left, right)?

Code:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import imutils

#cam def

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
cap = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))


#motor pins
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

RF1 = 27
RF2 = 9

RB1 = 22
RB2 = 13

LF1 = 3
LF2 = 13

LB1 = 11
LB2 = 9

buz = 10

#gpio setup and lowstart
GPIO.setup(RF1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RF2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RB1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RB2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LF1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LF2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LB1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LB2, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(buz, GPIO.OUT)


GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.output(buz, GPIO.LOW)


def rf(): #oldu

    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.HIGH)

def rb(): # oldu

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)

def lf(): #oldu

    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.LOW)

def lb(): #oldu

    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.HIGH)

def forward():


    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.HIGH)


    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.LOW)



def reverse():


    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.HIGH)

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.HIGH)


    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.HIGH)


    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.HIGH)


def rightturn():


    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.LOW)

def leftturn():


    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.LOW)

def stop1():


    GPIO.output(RF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RF2, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(RB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RB2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LF1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LF2, GPIO.LOW)


    GPIO.output(LB1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(LB2, GPIO.LOW)



#sensor part

TRIG = 20
ECHO = 21


GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

def sonar():

      start=0
      stop=0
      # SetPins
      GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
      GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)


      GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

      time.sleep(0.00001) #10uf call

      GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

      begin = time.time()

      while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0 and time.time()<begin+0.05:
          
         
          start = time.time()
          

      while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1 and time.time()<begin+0.01:
    
            stop = time.time()
            


      elapsed = stop-start

      distance = (elapsed / 0.000054)
    


      return distance

YellowLower = (0, 125, 88)
YellowUpper = (179, 255, 255)
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8); # for mask
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
#get frame after 2 seconds
#time.sleep(15)


for frame in camera.capture_continuous(cap, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

    frame = frame.array

    frame = cv2.flip(frame, -1) # flip 180 degree

    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5), 0) #smoothing

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, YellowLower, YellowUpper)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) # denoising

    frame_x, frame_y, _ = frame.shape

    min_area = 0; # min rect. shape w*h

    x_point = 0; # frame center

    y_point = 0;   #frame center

    #if camera find the ball

    if len(cnts) > 0:

        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea) #maximum contour

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        #x and y starting point, w and h height and width ratio

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3) # min rectangular drawing

        frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'Ball', (x+w-20,y+h+30), font, 1, (255,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        min_area = w*h #rectangular area

        x_point = x + (w/2) # obje center

        y_point = y + (h/2)

        
        dis = sonar() #distance

        if ((min_area > 700 ) and (min_area < 25000)) and (dis > 30):


            if x_point > ((frame_y/2) + (frame_y/3)):

                rightturn()

                time.sleep(0.5)

                stop1()

                print("turning right------")


            elif x_point < ((frame_y/2) - (frame_y/3)):


                leftturn()

                time.sleep(0.5)

                stop1()


                print("Turning left----------------")

            else:

                #time.sleep(0.5)

                forward()

                #time.sleep(2)


                print('go ahead--','dis is = ',dis,'area = ', min_area)


        elif dis < 5:

            time.sleep(0.5)

            stop1()

            print('target so close', 'distance is =  ',dis)

        elif (min_area > 300) and (min_area < 700)  :

            forward()

            time.sleep(2)

            stop1()

            time.sleep(1)

            print('too far, close it = ',dis, 'area = ', min_area)

    else:

        rightturn()

     


        #time.sleep(0.7)

       # stop()

        #time.sleep(1)

        print('there is no target, searching')

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    #cv2.imshow('masked ball', mask)

    # release cap

    cap.truncate(0)



    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):

        stop1()

        GPIO.cleanup()

        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Here is  [link]https://techatronic.com/raspberry-pi-motor-control/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).